# UDP Listener not working on different machine

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp, listener

I have an application with a UDP listener thread. This application works fine on one computer, but doesn't work on another. I have verified that the IP addresses are set to static and are within the same subnet, but for whatever reason the second computer can't listen to the data. It's the same Windows OS and everything.

I made sure the application was added to "Allow App Through Firewall", as well as creating an inbound rule to allow UDP on the port, but still no luck.

Is there anything else to check in order to make this work?

Here is how I'm connecting:

```
        udpClient = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient();
        udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(destIPAddr), System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(localIPAddress));
        ipEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, listenPort);  
        udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket, System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpClient.Client.Bind(ipEndPoint);   
        udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000; //5 second timeout
```

And I have a receive thread that's checking for data:

```
 retByte = udpClient.Receive(ref ipEndPoint);
```

When working, the bytes are displayed in a text box, as well as some other indicators that show that there is data being received.

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? Do you remember to check for errors everywhere in your code, and report errors if they happen? What *is* your code? Can you please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And don't forget to add the correct language tag.

Comment: You have a multicast IP address.  Most routes default to not passing multicast.  The IP is probably being blocked in the router and not being blocked by the firewall.